# Rails 3 engine which defines a custom logger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a test engine and I want to define a custom logger inside that engine which writes to a test.log file in the main app "logs" directory.

I tried defining it in the engine class but it's not working:

```
module Test

    class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
        isolate_namespace Test
        tracking_logger = Logger.new(Rails.root.join('log', "tracking.log"), 10, 30*1024*1024)
```

When I try to start the server it raises:
`<class:Engine>: undefined method join for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

which means that I can't see the main application root path from the engine itself. How would you suggest I get it up?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get your `app` instance. Do it in an `initializer` method. For example, to track locale setting:

```
module Test
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine

    initializer("your_engine.set_locale") do |app|
      tracking_logger = Logger.new(app.root.join('log', "tracking.log"), 10, 30*1024*1024)
      config.I18n.default_locale = :en
      tracking_logger.debug("My_Engine just set its custom locale to :en\n\n")
    end
```

But unfortunately I don't know how to pass this `tracking_logger` instance to other initilizers or methods. It is not good instantiating a new `tracking_logger` in every method I need to log something. A clue to how to instantiate it once and then have it between methods would be highly appreciated.